# Core Data: Copying NSManagedObject Using Category

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, objective-c-category

I have two entities:

- Ticket
- TicketResolved

Both entities have the same attributes.  What would be the the most efficient way to copy a `Ticket` `NSManagedObject` to `TicketResolved` `NSManagedObject`?

I'm thinking using a Category: `Ticket+Copy` be the least expensive way?  If so, I would have to `#import` both `Ticket` and `TicketResolved` in the Category file.

Here is what I came up with, can someone please advise if this is the right way of going about it.  I'm using `NSManagedObjectSubclass` for each entity.

Method in `Ticket+Copy`:

```
-(TicketResolved *)copyObjects:(Ticket *)ticket
{
     TicketResolved *ticketResolved = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TicketResolved" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
     ticketResolved.attribute = ticket.attribute;
     // Assign rest of the ticketResolved attributes values this way
     return ticketResolved;
}
```

Now calling the Method

```
#import Ticket;
#import Ticket+Copy;

@implementation
....
Ticket *ticket = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Ticket" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
TicketResolved *newTicketResolved = [ticket copyObjects:ticket];
// 'newTicketResolved' now has all the keys/values that 'ticket' had.
```

Is this a right approach or is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Maybe [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19189035/1990236) would work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Tom, I did correct my error in the question.

Below is the solution that worked for me:

```
TicketResolved *ticketResolved = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TicketResolved" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
NSArray *keys = [[[ticket entity] attributesByName] allKeys];
NSDictionary *dict= [ticket dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys];
[ticketResolved setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dict];
```

The code above does not copy the Relationships Objects.  For that I had to use the code below:

```
ticketResolved.relationshipObject = ticket.relationshipObject;
```

Answer (score 1):

If `Ticket` and `TicketResolved` actually have the same attributes, the **most efficient** option is to:

- Get rid of `TicketResolved`
- Add a boolean flag on `Ticket` named `resolved` that you can set to `YES` when the ticket is resolved.
- Use this attribute it fetch requests to get either resolved or non-resolved tickets, whichever you need.

Then you don't actually need to copy any data, and not doing work is always more efficient than doing it.

If for some reason you really want two separate entities with the same attributes, basically you have it, you need to create a `TicketResolved` instance and have your code copy over every attribute value. The only major problem with your code is lines like this:

```
Ticket *ticket = [Ticket alloc]init];
```

You can't create managed objects like that, because you're not calling the designated initializer. You need to either use `-[NSManagedObject initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:]` or else use `+[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:]`.

Comment: Thank you Tom.  You are right about the code being wrote.  I tried to simplify my question and made a mistake.

I did however accomplish what I was trying to using NSDictionary.  I'll paste the code below.  

Unfortunately, the requirement is indeed to have two separate entities.